# Dataproc serverless writing to Bigtable: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

How do I find out root cause? (I'm reading from Casssandra and writing to Bigtable)

I've tried:

- looking through Cassandra logs
- eliminating columns in case it was a data issue
- reducing spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows from 100 to 10
- spark.speculation both true and false
- etc.

It does load 100s of thousands of rows first before it throws the error. Bigtable has TBs of free space.

```
23/03/30 18:13:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) (10.128.0.46 executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: IllegalArgumentException: 1 time, servers with issues: bigtable.googleapis.com
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.getExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:188)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.handleExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:142)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.mutate(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:52)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1525)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: I would suggest to contact Google Support for this case to investigate further, and have the engineers to access logs or other details that otherwise not recommended to post publicly: https://cloud.google.com/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a few rows from Cassandra were corrupt: there were nulls in the keys for a few rows.  I discovered this accidentally after dumping the table to csv files and loading into another database.

After removing those corrupt rows, everything loaded fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that it's caused by IllegalArgumentException.

Given that you were able to write thousands of rows to Bigtable before it throws the error, it's likely that you hit the 100,000 mutation limit https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-operations. Note that this limit is on the number of mutations instead of number of rows.

It's possible that that some of the rows has too many columns, and each column is converted into a mutation https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writes#write-types.

You can try the following things:

1. Check how you're creating row mutations from your cassandra data.
2. Check if there are some rows with more than 10000 columns (assuming you're creating 1 mutation per column)